# Node js возвращает хтмл как текст

Tags: node.js, javascript, html

Ответ от сервера node.js приходит в виде скрипта

```
<script>parent.callbackRegistry[window.name]("123")</script>
```

но браузер его отображает как текст, оборачивая в тэг pre, как сделать что бы функция вызвалась.
вот такая отвечает сервер

```
response.end('<script>parent.callbackRegistry[window.name]("123")</script>');
```

Вставить скрипт к примеру через innerHTML не могу, так как он возвращается в iframe, да и в общем интересно как вернуть html страницу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

хидер, надеюсь, добавили?..

```
response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html" });
```

Comment: Спасибо, не заметил что у меня стоит 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' , раз 5 смотрел на заголовки и впритык не видел(